# how is Maven 3 host look up different to Maven 2?

Tags: maven, build, artifactory

I am working to migrate from Maven 2 to Maven 3.  I have purposely removed the host and port from the messages and settings.

Maven 2 currently works fine with the Artifactory central repository we have setup behind a firewall.  When I switch to using Maven 3 it fails to download the plugins with the error message:

> [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3.1 or
>   one of its  dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read
>   artifact descriptor for org.
>   apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.3.1: Could not
>   transfer artifact 
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:pom:2.3.1 from/to
>   central (http:/ /:/artifactory/plugins-release): Access
>   denied to:
>   http://:/artifactory/plugins-release/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.3.1/maven-install-plugin-2.3.1.pom
>   , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden.

Here are my settings:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>andy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxyip</host>
      <port>80</port>
      <username>user</username>
      <password>password</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>host</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy> 
  </proxies>
      <servers>
        <server>
          <username>user</username>
          <password>password</password>
          <id>central</id>
        </server>
        <server>
      <username>user</username>
      <password>password</password>
      <id>snapshots</id>
    </server>
  </servers>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>libs-release</name>
          <url>http://<host>:<port>/artifactory/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <snapshots />
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>libs-snapshot</name>
          <url>http://<host>:<port>/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>plugins-release</name>
          <url>http://<host>:<port>/artifactory/plugins-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots />
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>plugins-snapshot</name>
          <url>http://<host>:<port>/artifactory/plugins-snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
      <id>artifactory</id>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

I have checked that the correct plugin and version exists in artifactory, this does seem to be an access issue.  Has something changed between Maven 2 and Maven 3 where the configuration needs updating?

Comment: I have found out that this is being caused because Maven 3 is trying to find the host through the proxy, not on the local network.. This means that the question becomes, how is Maven 3 host look up different to Maven 2?

Comment: <nonProxyHosts>host</nonProxyHosts> <-- This tag stops it using the proxy, I put this in to stop maven 3 host look up going to the proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by re-downloading and refreshing my Maven 3 install.  There must have been something wrong with the install.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the configuration (probably `settings.xml` or a POM file): `http://:/artifactory/` isn't a valid URL, try `http://artifactory/` instead.

**EDIT** If the URL is valid in a browser, then Maven has no access.

What the error message says: Maven tried to download the file and the server responded with [HTTP status 403 (Forbidden)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error). Since it works with a web browser, this is most certainly a problem with `settings.xml` and permissions on the Artifactory server.

I once had a similar problem with Nexus; it was configured to deny access to certain packages.

Check the log files of the repository server. You can also try to remove any `<server>` entries in `settings.xml` - the browser also connects without logging in. And (of course) make sure user names and passwords are correct.

Comment: I took out the hostname and port to protect company id.  I copied and pasted the link in the error message into the internet browser and it works (starts downloading the pom).

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer!
The same settings work with maven 2 which suggests it can not be a password issue, I removed the server definition and still had the same problem.

Comment: I had a look at the server logs and it looks like maven 3 never reaches the server so it is the networking or host determination which is failing.  I am going to try and install a local copy of artifactory to see if that will resolve the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, debugging network issues isn't easy with Maven since the debug output (enabled with `-X`) won't include anything useful. [Maven 3.1 will improve this](http://maven.apache.org/maven-logging.html) by allowing you to configure the log output (i.e. you can make the wagon/network parts more chatty).

Comment: @AndrewFlatt: Did you check the HTTP proxy settings? Maybe your HTTP proxy needs username+password.

Answer (score 0):

You defined a proxy between your machine and your Artifactory server on the intranet. Usually, that is not the correct setup. Artifactory might need a proxy to reach the servers on the internet (the remote repositories), but maven probably must access Artifactory without proxy.